# How can I change the result of torch.cuda.is_available() to True GTX 1050ti

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

hello i have recently started using pytorch but now i need to use my GPU which is a **Nvidia GTX 1050ti** to process some data but unfortunately torch.cuda.is_available() is returning False i have tried uninstaling **cudatoolkit 11.3** and downgrade it to `11.1` and also deleating and reinstaling pytorch using `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia -c conda-forge`, here's some information about my local configuration :

```
OS : windows 10 
graphical card : nvidia 1050ti
current nvidia driver : 465.89
```

```
>>> torch.version.cuda
'11.1'
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
False
>>> torch.backends.cudnn.enabled
True
>>> torch.__version__
'1.8.1'
```

```
   ->   nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Sep_15_19:12:04_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.1, V11.1.74
Build cuda_11.1.relgpu_drvr455TC455_06.29069683_0
```

Comment: What's the output of [collect_env.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/pytorch/master/torch/utils/collect_env.py) script?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1640qny

Comment: Did you solve it? If yes - how?

Comment: to awnser the question of @PabloDK well not really i changed my laptop and it's working with my new laptop but i believe i missed something as a result there was a version confli

Answer (score 2):

You have probably downloaded the only-cpu version.

Have you tried to install it using pip and the stable pytorch version?

```
pip install torch torchvision -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Make sure to purge your pip cache before so you won't install the same chached wheels:

```
pip uninstall torch
pip chache purge
```

Then run the above mentioned install instruction.